# No puedo redimensionar disco cifrado Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, almacenamiento, linuxlite

Llevo usando Pop!OS un tiempo sin intenciones de tenerlo en dual boot, sin embargo necesito instalar Win 10 en segundo plano. Gparted no me deja redimensionarlo y al parecer mi disco es intocable, lo tengo cifrado por cierto.

A pesar de que el sistema reconoce que el disco no esta lleno en Gparted aparece como si no hubiera espacio disponible cuanod lo voy a redimensionar.

Alguien sabe como forzar la particion o si es necesario desencriptar.

Comment: si tienes problemas con algo lo basico.. te sale mejor instalar windows primero y luego ubuntu, ya que windows sobrescribe el arranque por lo que se perdera el grub de ubuntu y deberas reinstalarlo y lleva algo mas de complejidad....

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.